# Python searching in nested lists to find values and insert values into a new list

Tags: python, search, insert, compare, nested-lists

I am having trouble figuring out how to search through nested lists that I have in order to find certain values for the purpose of adding different values to another nested list if that makes sense? I will try to explain below.

```
list1 = [[P1, 3, P2, 1],[P3, 2, P4, 1][P5, 3, P6, 2]]
```

Basically this nested list represents scores for rounds in a game between players (P1 scored 3 points against  P2 and P2 scored 1 against P1).

I also have a second nested list:

```
list2 = [[P1], [P2], [P3], [P4], [P5], [P6]]
```

The second nested list will represent ranking scores between players. What I am trying to achieve is inserting a ranking score into the second nested list based on the players score in the first nested list. For example, in "list1" P1, P3 and P5 won their rounds and therefore I would like to insert a ranking score of "5"(arbitrary number for demonstrative purposes) into "list2" for those players and "0" for the other players so that the list will look something like this:

```
list2 = [[P1, 5], [P2, 0], [P3, 5], [P4, 0], [P5, 5], [P6, 0]]
```

I am struggling to figure out the logic behind how to do this so any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: You might find `dict`s useful, since you can use Playernames as keys directly. Then iterate over your first list and compare scores and give the player in your dictionary 5 points. :)

Comment: If I may suggest - I'd use something besides lists to keep track of the ranking - lists are great up to a certain size but eventually they'd lose out in performance compared to a `dict`, for example.

Comment: What about a tie or rematches?

Comment: You are also missing a comma between `[P3, 2, P4, 1]` and `[P5, 3, P6, 2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dict` you can try something like

```
list1 = [["P1", 3, "P2", 1],["P3", 2, "P4", 1],["P5", 3, "P6", 2]]
playerDict = {"P1":0,"P2":0,"P3":0,"P4":0,"P5":0,"P6":0}

for entry in list1:
    if entry[1] > entry[3]:
        playerDict[entry[0]] = 5
    else:
        playerDict[entry[2]] = 5
```

Output for playerDict:

```
{'P1': 5, 'P3': 5, 'P6': 0, 'P2': 0, 'P5': 5, 'P4': 0}
```

And some more info for you if you like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm :)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the example that's a huge help and I really appreciate it  I will try and wrap my head around using dictionaries :D

Comment: This would break in case of a rematch

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
P1 = "Team1"
P2 = "Team2"
P3 = "Team3"
P4 = "Team4"
P5 = "Team5"
P6 = "Team6"
n = 5
import itertools
list1 = [[P1, 3, P2, 1],[P3, 2, P4, 1], [P5, 3, P6, 2]]
final_data = list(itertools.chain(*[[[t1, n], [t2, 0]] if s1 > s2 else [[t1, 0], [t2, n]] for t1, s1, t2, s2 in list1]))
```

Output:

```
[['Team1', 5], ['Team2', 0], ['Team3', 5], ['Team4', 0], ['Team5', 5], ['Team6', 0]]
```

Comment: I like your use of itertools, however your answer breaks in case of a rematch or a tie

Answer (score 0):

For your first comparison, assuming the format remains like this:

```
list1 = [[P1, 3, P2, 1],[P3, 2, P4, 1][P5, 3, P6, 2]]
```

The most basic comparison you could do is:

```
for score_list in list1:
    # score_list[1] and score_list[3] are the scores
    if score_list[1] > score_list[3]:
        # winner is player in score_list[0]
        winner = score_list[0]
        loser = score_list[2]
    elif score_list[1] < score_list[3]:
        winner = score_list[2]
        loser = score_list[0]
    else:
        # what do you do in case of a tie?
        pass

    # now do something with the winner information
    # if we're keeping list2 format, you'd have to scan
    # the list until you find the one where the first element
    # is the winner, and also do something for the loser
    for player_list in list2:
        if player_list[0] == winner:
            player_list.append(5)
        if player_list[0] == loser:
            player_list.append(0)
```

You can improve the `list2` processing by instead using a dictionary, which lets you map keys to values.

```
players = {
    'P1': [],
    'P2': [],
    'P3': [],
     # ...and so on...
}

scores = [[P1, 3, P2, 1],[P3, 2, P4, 1],[P5, 3, P6, 2]]

for score in scores:
    if score_list[1] > score_list[3]:
        # winner is player in score_list[0]
        winner = score_list[0]
        loser = score_list[2]
    elif score_list[1] < score_list[3]:
        winner = score_list[2]
        loser = score_list[0]
    else:
        # what do you do in case of a tie?
        pass

    players[winner].append(5)
    players[loser].append(0)
```

Comment: Hey I really appreciate the example it's a huge help in trying to understand the logic behind it :D I think I may now attempt to do it using dictionaries as yourself and others have pointed out if it is a more efficient method. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, my guess is that lists are not arbitrarily nested and that you do not actually search for values but instead want to transform the nested list into another form.

However, thinking your example further, my guess is, that players might have repeated matches and thus might have more than one won match? My guess is also that a tie might occur in one of the matches.

In either case, the lookup logic is quite costly and I would recommend using a dictionary instead to count the points. In there, you could simply look up the player name `P1, P2, ...` and increment the amount of points stored there.

In this case, you could iterate through all matches, unpacking the nested lists on the go and compare points. based on the comparison result, you could update the players dictionary accordingly:

```
list1 = [["P1", 3, "P2", 1], ["P3", 2, "P4", 1], ["P5", 3, "P6", 2]]
player_points = {}
for player_1_name, player_1_points, player_2_name, player_2_points in list1:
    if player_1_points > player_2_points:
        player_1_points = 5
        player_2_points = 0
    elif player_1_points < player_2_points:
        player_1_ponints = 0
        player_2_points = 5
    else:    # Player 1 and 2 are tied
        player_1_points = 2
        player_2_points = 2
    if player_1_name not in player_points:
        player_points[player_1_name] = 0
    if player_2_name not in player_points:
        player_points[player_2_name] = 0
    player_points[player_1_name] += player_1_points
    player_points[player_2_name] += player_2_points
```

After the run, the dictionary would look like this:

```
{'P2': 0, 'P3': 5, 'P1': 5, 'P6': 0, 'P4': 0, 'P5': 5}
```

If you really want to have a list of tuples, you could convert the dictionary to such a list like this:

```
list2 = list(player_points.items())
```

Output:

```
[('P2', 0), ('P3', 5), ('P1', 5), ('P6', 0), ('P4', 0), ('P5', 5)]
```

If you really also need lists inside, this would do the trick:

```
list2 = [list(item) for item in player_points.items()]
```

Output:

```
[['P2', 0], ['P3', 5], ['P1', 5], ['P6', 0], ['P4', 0], ['P5', 5]]
```

You could even sort by player name by sprinkling in `sorted`:

```
list2 = [list(item) for item in sorted(player_points.items())]
```

Output:

```
[['P1', 5], ['P2', 0], ['P3', 5], ['P4', 0], ['P5', 5], ['P6', 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another not so elegant but functional solution would be this:

```
list1 = [['P1', 3, 'P2', 1],['P3', 2, 'P4', 1],['P5', 3, 'P6', 2]]
list2 = []

def takeScore(list1, list2, number):
    for i in list1:
        if i[1] > i[3]:
            list2.extend(([i[0],number],[i[2],0]))
        else:
            list2.extend(([i[1],0],[i[2],number]))

takeScore(list1,list2,5)
print(list2)
```

The result is:

```
[['P1', 5], ['P2', 0], ['P3', 5], ['P4', 0], ['P5', 5], ['P6', 0]]
```